# View não retornando os dados atualizados do BD

Tags: jpa-2.0, spring-data

tenho uma view de banco que quando cadastro um novo registro a mesma view traz os valores desatualizados para minha listagem. Ela só traz os dados de forma atualizado se eu derrubar o servidor e subir novamente.

estou usando Spring Data e abaixo segue mais detalhes para ajudar:

```
@RequestMapping("/serviceList")
public ModelAndView getMenuServiceList(Model model) {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("service/serviceList");

    // Dados estão chegando desatualizados!!!
    List<VwOpenService> openServiceList = serviceFacade.getOpenServiceList();       

    mv.addObject("serviceListRegister", openServiceList);
    countOfBudgets(model);  
    return mv;
}
```

**Camada de Serviço**

```
public List<VwOpenService> getOpenServiceList() {
    return vwOpenService.findAll();
}
```

**Repositorio (Spring Data)**

```
@Repository
public interface OpenServiceRepository extends BaseRepository<VwOpenService, Long>{

    List<VwOpenService> findAll();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema era unica e exclusivamente relacionado com cache, logo bastou adicionar a seguinte propriedade em minha entidade `@Cache(isolation=CacheIsolationType.ISOLATED)` do *Eclipselink* que acabou sanando o problema.